# Merge rows of item column having the same date column and display items in single row in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making an online shopping cart website and the customer must view all his/her orders in a table with all the order information like item names, price, date ordered, etc. And I want to group each order by date and display the items with same date in one row.

My table looks like this:

| Orders | Date Ordered |
| --- | --- |
| item1 | 11-23-2021 |
| item2 | 11-23-2021 |
| item3 | 12-30-2021 |

I want it to look like this:

| Orders | Date Ordered |
| --- | --- |
| item1, item2 | 11-23-2021 |
| item3 | 12-30-2021 |

PHP:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Orders</th>
    <th>Date Ordered</th>
  </tr>

  <?php
   $showOrder = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM orderdetails WHERE dateOrdered = '11-23-2021'
                            GROUP BY orderDate");

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($showOrder)){
                    $item = $row['item'];
                    $date = $row['dateOrdered']; ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo "<p>".$item."</p>"; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo "<p>".$date."</p>"; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT in MySQL query. For example,

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(orders), date_ordered FROM orderdetails WHERE dateOrdered = '11-23-2021' GROUP BY orderDate
```

I presume your orderDate table has orders and date_ordered fields, You can modify according to your actual table column names.

You can read details like your own delimeters etc. [here](https://database.guide/how-to-return-query-results-as-a-comma-separated-list-in-mysql/)

Comment: Great! I also have added URL where you can read more on GROUP_CONCAT cheers!